# Why is a string that is saved to local storage from a form input blank?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, local-storage

I'm trying to make a form that saves the data when the user presses a button.

```
   <form>
   <label for="name">Name:</label>
   <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
   <label for="age">Age:</label>
   <input type="text" id="age" name="age">
   <button type="button" onclick="SaveData()">Save Data</button>
   <button type="button" onclick="LoadData()">Load Data</button>
   </form>
```

Here is my attempt. When I try to load the data, it is just blank.

```
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
function SaveData() {
    localStorage.setItem("name", name);     
}
function LoadData() {
    var data = localStorage.getItem("name");
    alert(data);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: @A.Meshu that question seems to be about storing non-string values in localStorage, whereas this question seems to be about storing string values.

Comment: @MarkHanna I apologize - you right. Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check `#name` value inside the function.

```
function SaveData() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  localStorage.setItem("name", name);     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that `name` is set outside `saveData()` and never updated. Thus, whenever `saveData()` is called, it's always storing the original value of `name`, which (since the form input has no default) is the empty string. Thus it's more accurate to say that it's loading the default value, rather than a blank value.

To store the current value of the input, you'll need to update `name` before each time `saveData()` is called or access the value directly in `saveData()`. Since there are multiple inputs, you'd need to do this for each input. A simple solution is to pass the form to `saveData()` and have it examine [each of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) the [inputs in the form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements):

```
function saveData(form) {
    for (elt of form.elements) {
        if (elt.id || elt.name) {
            localStorage.setItem(elt.id || elt.name, elt.value);
        }
    }
}
```

The "Save" form button would be updated as:

```
<button type="button" onclick="SaveData(this.form)">Save Data</button>
```

You can make similar changes to `LoadData()` and the "Load" button.

Instead of calling the data saving & loading functions from the `onclick` properties, you could also make use of [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) (which has certain advantages, as outlined both in the linked MDN document and "[addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6348494/90527)" here on SO), though passing the form would be handled differently.

Answer (score 1):

```html
  <form onsubmit="onSave()">
   <label for="name">Name:</label>
   <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
   <label for="age">Age:</label>
   <input type="text" id="age" name="age">
   <input type="submit" value="Save Data" />
   <button type="button" onclick="LoadData()">Load Data</button>
   </form>
```

```js
function onSave(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const { currentTarget } = event;
    const data = new FormData(currentTarget)
    Array.from(data.entries()).forEach(function([key, value]) {
      window.localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    })
}
```

OR

```html
  <form id="form">
   <label for="name">Name:</label>
   <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
   <label for="age">Age:</label>
   <input type="text" id="age" name="age">
   <button type="button" onclick="SaveData()">Save Data</button>
   <button type="button" onclick="LoadData()">Load Data</button>
   </form>
```

```js
const form = document.getElementById("form")
function onSave(event){
    const data = new FormData(form)
    Array.from(data.entries()).forEach(function([key, value]) {
      window.localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    })
}
```

Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Besides the mistake of acquiring `name` not from within the `SaveData` function one does not really want to save all the form data form-control wise each as key-value to the local storage. One should think about saving all of it.

A viable approach was to utilize both [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) and [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) in order to store all the form's active data at once under a single form related/specific key.

```js
// local storage mock due to SO blocking
// built-in `localStorage` by privacy settings.
const localStorage = {
  storage: new Map,
  setItem(key, value) {
    this.storage.set(key, value);
  },
  getItem(key) {
    return this.storage.get(key) ?? null;
  }
};

function saveData(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  const elmForm = evt.currentTarget;
  const storageKey = elmForm.dataset.storableForm;

  const activeData = Object.fromEntries(
    Array.from(
      new FormData(elmForm).entries()
    )
  );
  localStorage.setItem(
    storageKey,
    JSON.stringify(activeData)
  );

  // debug logging.
  console.log({
    [storageKey]: localStorage.getItem(storageKey)
  });
}
function loadData(evt) {
  const elmForm = evt.currentTarget.form;
  const storageKey = elmForm.dataset.storableForm;

  const storageData = JSON.parse(
    localStorage.getItem(storageKey)
  );
  Object
    .entries(storageData ?? {})
    .forEach(([key, value]) => {
      elmForm.elements[key].value = value;
    });

  // debug logging.
  console.log({ storageData });
}

document
  .querySelectorAll('[data-storable-form]')
  .forEach(elmNode => {
    elmNode
      .addEventListener('submit', saveData);
    elmNode
     .querySelector('[data-load]')
     .addEventListener('click', loadData);
  });
```

```css
body { margin: 0; zoom: .95; }
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 85%!important; }
```

```html
<form data-storable-form="form-data-A">
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name">

  <label for="age">Age:</label>
  <input type="text" id="age" name="age">

  <button type="submit">Save Data</button>

  <button type="reset" onclick="console.clear();">Clear Data</button>

  <button type="button" data-load>Load Data</button>
</form>
```